# React component does not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a React microfrontend application. I have put together two sub apps so far that are rendered via the `container/` project. In isolation, on localhost:8083 I can see the sub app rendering just nicely, but unlike the other sub apps, when I need to view it via localhost:8080/dashboard, I get nothing but a white screen and worse, no error in terminal, no error in console, no error in network requests.

This is my `webpack.dev.js` file in `container/`:

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const commonConfig = require("./webpack.common");
const packageJson = require("../package.json");

const devConfig = {
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:8080/",
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "container",
      remotes: {
        marketing: "marketing@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js",
        auth: "auth@http://localhost:8082/remoteEntry.js",
        dashboard: "dashboard@http://localhost:8083/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      shared: packageJson.dependencies,
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, devConfig);
```

I have looked at this repeatedly, don't see anything wrong there.

This is the `webpack.common.js` file I have in that `container/` folder:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime']
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html'
    }),
  ]
}
```

I have looked at that and don't see anything wrong there.

Here is my `components/DashboardApp.js` file inside of `container/`:

```
import { mount } from "dashboard/DashboardApp";
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default ({ onSignIn }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    const { onParentNavigate } = mount(ref.current, {
      initialPath: history.location.pathname,
      onNavigate: ({ pathname: nextPathname }) => {
        const { pathname } = history.location;

        if (pathname !== nextPathname) {
          history.push(nextPathname);
        }
      },
      onSignIn,
    });

    history.listen(onParentNavigate);
  }, []);

  return <div ref={ref} />;
};
```

My `container/src/App.js` file:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  StylesProvider,
  createGenerateClassName,
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import Progress from "./components/Progress";
import Header from "./components/Header";

const MarketingLazy = lazy(() => import("./components/MarketingApp"));
const AuthLazy = lazy(() => import("./components/AuthApp"));
const DashboardLazy = lazy(() => import("./components/DashboardApp"));

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  productionPrefix: "co",
});

export default () => {
  const [isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = useState(false);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
        <div>
          <Header
            onSignOut={() => setIsSignedIn(false)}
            isSignedIn={isSignedIn}
          />
          <Suspense fallback={<Progress />}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/auth'>
                <AuthLazy onSignIn={() => setIsSignedIn(true)} />
              </Route>
              <Route path='/dashboard' component={DashboardLazy} />
              <Route path='/' component={MarketingLazy} />
            </Switch>
          </Suspense>
        </div>
      </StylesProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Can anyone see anything I may have missed? Why would this component not render through the `container/` whereas the other sub apps built exactly the same can.

Comment: is your remote entry url is valid?  marketing: "marketing@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js"

Comment: Take a look this url https://blog.bitsrc.io/revolutionizing-micro-frontends-with-webpack-5-module-federation-and-bit-99ff81ceb0, looks like contentBase is missing

Comment: @Sam, I just tried contentBase and that did not render the sub app, looks the same as before.

Comment: @Sam, yes this `marketing: "marketing@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js",` is valid, I am not having any problem with it or the `auth` one either.

Comment: Glad , you are able to make it work, How are you finding module federation so far. do you have any other issue ?. We are planning to use in our application, just want to know how is it so far?

Comment: @Sam, I am enjoying the benefits of it and suffering through the downsides. For example, on a couple of occassions I get the following error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dashboard/DashboardApp'`. In fact, I am suffering through this one right now and was planning to post it on SO. I had the same issue with other sub apps and through a process of just trying different things, I got it to work, but here I am again. It seems like everytime I add a new sub app this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an application starts to grow in complexity, it's the smallest detail. While my `container/src/App.js` file had a `path="/dashboard"`, my `dashboard/src/App.js` file did not, it looked like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Router } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  StylesProvider,
  createGenerateClassName,
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  productionPrefix: "da",
});

export default ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </StylesProvider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Once I changed it to this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Router } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  StylesProvider,
  createGenerateClassName,
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  productionPrefix: "da",
});

export default ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </StylesProvider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now it displays inside parent container.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing contentBase.

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    port: 3002,
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3002/",
  },
```